# Packet corruption during download, then ffmpeg hangs

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I was getting corrupted packets during capture of an `m3u8` playlist, so I added the `+discardcorrupt` flag, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61094754).

However, this results in a program hang. The stream steadily slows to a trickle, and then it just stops.

How can I successfully download this MP4 without curruption?

Here's my input and output:

**Input**

```
ffmpeg -fflags +discardcorrupt -i https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/master.m3u8 -c copy "D:\Download\Hunting for Viruses with Dr. Andy Kaufman.mp4"
```

**Output**

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-08-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:6')
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/stream_0.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:6')
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Skip ('#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS')
[https @ 000001d181f99080] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/stream_1.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:6')
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Skip ('#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS')
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_1_000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_1_000001.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/master.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:35:40.92, start: 1.400000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 3660800
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 150 fps, 150 tbr, 90k tbn, 300 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 3660800
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 3660800
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 844800
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 150 fps, 150 tbr, 90k tbn, 300 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 844800
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 844800
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\Download\Hunting for Viruses with Dr_ Andy Kaufman.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 150 fps, 150 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 3660800
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 3660800
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[https @ 000001d1821692c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000002.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] No longer receiving playlist 1 ('https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/stream_1.m3u8')
[https @ 000001d182330300] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000003.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d1821692c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000004.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d182330300] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000005.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000005.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 3336290), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d1821692c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000006.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000007.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 5102690), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d1821692c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000008.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000008.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 3489926016), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f45fc0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000009.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000009.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000010.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 7757090), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000011.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 8886890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d1822e4340] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000012.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000012.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 9770690), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f45fc0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000013.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000013.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 10461890), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000014.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000015.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 12278690), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f32140] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000016.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183e31b40] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000017.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000017.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 14106890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f32140] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000018.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000018.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 14993090), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000019.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000020.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 16757090), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e31b40] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000021.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183f32140] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000022.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000022.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 18876290), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e31b40] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000023.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000023.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 19536290), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000024.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 20383490), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000025.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 21246890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f45fc0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000026.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000026.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 22181690), dropping it.
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] PES packet size mismatch4:10.00 bitrate=2264.8kbits/s speed=0.701x
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 22167078), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e31680] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000027.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000027.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 23085890), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000028.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000029.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 25266890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d1828ca980] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000030.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000030.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 25746890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e9b600] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000031.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000032.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 27648890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e9b600] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000033.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000033.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 28517090), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183ea72c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000034.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000034.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 29357090), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000035.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000036.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 31183490), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e9b600] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000037.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183ea72c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000038.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000038.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 32946890), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e9b600] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000039.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000040.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 34768547), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183e9b600] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000041.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000041.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183ea72c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000042.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000043.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183ea72c0] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000044.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000044.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 38393090), dropping it.
[https @ 000001d183f46000] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000045.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000045.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000046.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001d182049c00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 40159490), dropping it.
[hls @ 000001d1800a5380] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000047.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001d183f32140] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000048.ts' for reading
frame=52343 fps= 80 q=-1.0 size=  140800kB time=00:08:23.34 bitrate=2291.5kbits/s speed=0.77x
```

**--EDIT--**

Per Gyan's suggestion, I removed the `+discardcorrupt` flag. Now I'm getting this with nearly every attempt, albeit at random times during the capture:

```
[hls @ 000001f2611e5180] Opening 'https://usw-p1.lbryplayer.xyz/api/v4/streams/tc/Odysee-Hunting-Viruses-With-Andy-Kaufmann-1-comp/71890eecf62e1d2ae1bf6c24663c6cf668ec6de9/022a34c2d71e9a7ea4bbdd01cddfd96ef4b044d37436e89e248afe238579ff779b3b872fb3dc98e8b612ad94b14f604c/seg_0_000034.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 000001f2630ee980] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 29472890).
[mpegts @ 000001f2630ee980] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 000001f2630ee980] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 29458376).
[aac_adtstoasc @ 000001f263979f00] Error parsing ADTS frame header!
[mp4 @ 000001f2638a5b40] Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #1: Invalid data found when processing input
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input
frame=36239 fps= 84 q=-1.0 Lsize=   98551kB time=00:05:30.16 bitrate=2445.2kbits/s speed=0.764x
video:94099kB audio:3842kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.621808%
Conversion failed!
```

Those attempts that don't produce this error eventually fall into the ffmpeg hang.

Answer (score 2):

Don't drop the "corrupt" packets.

Within HLS input consisting of MPEG-TS segments, each media packet consists of a continuity counter. The CC of the initial packet of a segment is supposed to follow on from the last packet of the prior segment. Some HLS packagers, including ffmpeg, reset these CC across segments (limitation rather than choice).

When demuxing, the HLS packager presents the concatenated media as a single stream and the child MPEG-TS demuxer expects the CC to remain continuous, which it isn't, so it flags it as corrupt. Nothing wrong with the actual media data.

Comment: Interesting nuance, thanks. That must be what's behind this: `(stream = 0, dts = 29472890)`, yes? Anyway, there's a new error condition after removing the flag. It's occurring on nearly every attempt, at varying times, but always within the first few minutes of the stream. What do you make of it?

Comment: This error `Error parsing ADTS frame header!` looks like an actual corrupt packet.

Comment: Yes, I would tend to agree. Are you aware of a way to retry (truly) corrupted packets? I poked around some but didn't find anything.

Comment: If you think it's due to transport corruption, download the segments manually e.g. curl and then check.

Comment: Good idea, that :-) I will commence.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I downloaded all the segments in a separate action, and then ran `ffmpeg` against the local stream. Thank you! Care to make that into another answer, so I can send some rep your way?

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to recommend [FDM](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) for these types of downloads (not affiliated, just very pleased). Paste your URL list, specify a folder and you're off and running. It spawns separate download threads, tracks progress and retries failures. You can't go wrong.

Comment: Readers will follow the comments so no need for a new answer. As for downloading, aria2c is a good cli client.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at aria2c